# How UC Browser's cloud acceleration works?

Tags: caching, proxy, performance-testing, uc-browser

I am searching for documentation related to the **cloud acceleration** feature of **UC Browser**, but can't find any useful resource.

Chrome's data saver feature is documented well. Is there any similar document that explains the UC Browser's cloud acceleration feature in detail? I specifically need answers to the following questions, if anyone can help:

1. Does UC Browser proxy HTTPS requests too through their cloud servers? If so, how does it handle caching in this scenario?
2. How does the proxy server identify itself to the origin server, and how does it forward user's IP address to the origin?
3. Does the UC Browser's cloud server cache static resources?
4. The proxy servers are known to compress/minify/optimize resources. How does it work with Subresource Integrity?
5. Does proxy server support Brotli encoding both ways (origin to proxy and proxy to browser)?

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Strange someone voted to close this question arguing that it is not related to programming. Do I have to copy a code snippet in the question to make it look relevant? Aren't proxies, web development, HTTP cache etc all related to programming?

Comment: It depends. Someone considers it a proper question on SO, someone wants it migrated to e.g. SuperUser or some other sub-site of StackExchange depending on the context. Just ignore it, questions can be closed and immediately reopened after. :)

Answer (score 2):

Features like cloud acceleration and other data saving technologies won't touch https resources. Proxy servers often add an extra header 'X-FORWARDED-FOR' containing user IP. Probably UC optimizes the images and caches a smaller images by scaling down its dimensions. The subresource integrity is a client side check and browser can decide how to implement it and UC Browser doesn't support it yet.

Comment: 1). Opera's turbo feature forwards https requests too (maybe in limited cases) through their datacenters. So, its probable that UC may also do it. 2). Yes, I just checked UC does not support SRI yet, but a resource optimized this way definitely cannot pass integrity check..... For the time being, I am not selecting this answer because it does not provide specific information.

Comment: Opera Turbo won't compress/ optimizes https requests, the purpose of https is defeated if a proxy can tamper an https request. And the current SRI Spec is only for Javascript and CSS resources where as turbo and cloud accelerate only optimizes images and corrects video buffering.